# Import all resources defined in tf file

Tags: terraform

Let's say I've used Terraform to build my infrastructure and my tfstate gets deleted for some reason. This means I already have my resources defined in tf files, I just need to re-import everything.

Does this have to be a manual process?

For example this is how I import an EC2 instance:

```
terraform import aws_instance.web i-123456
```

If I have to do that for every resource, that's quite painful (might as well delete everything and start over).

If I already have my tf files is there a way to just import all the resources that have been defined in them? For example I needed the instance ID in order to import that instance. Can the Terraform import command just read my tf file and find the resource mapped to "aws_instance.web"?

In order to do this Terraform would need to have a mapping of that aws instance to the resource in the tf file- this is of course the purpose of the tfstate. But does Terraform have a way of also tagging resources with their resource mappings? So I can do an import against a tf file and terraform just dynamically reads the tf file and finds the physical resources corresponding to the tf resources by unique tags?

Comment: How would that work if you'd defined two identical resources?

Comment: How do you mean? Like if I had two different tf files that defined a resource of the same name? Sorry still wrapping my head around terraform so maybe I'm missing something here?

Comment: Yeah, kind of.  If you'd defined two EC2 instances (for example) with the exact same parameters, how would Terraform know which is which without storing the mapping to instance IDs?

Comment: hmm well assuming I have just one tf file wouldn't each resource defined in that file need to have a unique name? So if those instances were themselves tagged with that mapping terraform could know which is which right?

Comment: In theory, yes.  But in general not all resources are "taggable".  (Well, they might be in AWS, I don't know.  But they're certainly not in general.)

Comment: OK yes I was thinking about that. The resources would need to allow support for storing some sort of metadata along with them. So I guess the answer to my question is no. To perhaps rephrase my question, is there a best practice for defining resources that would be easier to re-import in case the tfstate gets corrupt? Or any way of making this process less painful and manual, because thats what I"m most concerned about

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there's no way to do this natively in Terraform; and even if you scripted a way together - I don't think it'd be very reliable and you wouldn't be able to trust that it selected the right resource (At least not easily).

Terraform says multiple times in the documentation that you need to protect your state file; this is why remote stores, such as S3 are encouraged for anything you care about; and also why this is a selling point of Terraform Enterprise.

Comment: So sounds like if you use terraform your infrastructure better be dynamic enough so you can build a completely new version of it and migrate to that in the event your state gets corrupt otherwise your screwed.

Comment: @red888 I mean that's really true for anything you use. Terraform recommends using S3 as a data store and ensuring you have versioning enabled.

Comment: A lot of resources can be identified unambiguously; for example is a template says to make an AWS S3 with name pineapple, well, there is globally at most one aws bucket with that name.  Ditto roles and policies and a lot of other resources.  Of those where there is some ambiguity, such as instances, the list of possible targets can be presented to the user to choose the right one.  It looks to me as if tf actively discourages such approaches because it is not in their commercial interest to do so, not because it is not possible.