# How can I import all the existing infrastructure state from aws and compare it with the generated reverse-terraformed resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am currently trying to reverse-terraform existing infrastructure (on aws) using [Terraformer](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer). I have managed to import some resources via:

```
terraformer import aws --resources=vpc,subnet,ec2_instance,s3 --connect=true --profile=default
```

However, I would like to test if these resources match the current terraform state (existing infrastructure). I found that I can use the Terraform [import](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/import.html) command like:

```
terraform import module.foo.aws_instance.bar i-abcd1234
```

To my understanding, this command is more intended to import existing infrastructure one-by-one. However, I would like to import all the existing infrastructure at once. In other words, I want to import the state of all the existing infrastructure and compare it with the generated resources from Terraformer to make sure that terraform code matches the current infrastructure 1 to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you written Terraform definitions, or are you just using the definitions produced by Terraformer?

---

If you are just using the Terraformer definitions (which I assume is your situation), you can run

```
terraform plan
```

in the directory where Terraformer has put those defs, and Terraform will show what it wants to change. If it shows that it doesn't want to change anything, then that means the definitions match the existing state.

---

If you have hand-written definitions, then you will have to use `terraform import` one at a time, because Terraform has no other way to identify which actual resources correspond to which defined resources.

Comment: I ran `terraform plan` after running `terraformer import`. However, the plan command tells me it wants to create those resources again. I'm not sure how to proceed since the configuration files were generated by terraformer.

Comment: @karanmirani did `terraformer` produce a `.tfstate` file? If so, does it look like all your resources are represented in it?

Comment: yes, `terraformer` did generate a `.tfstate` file but only for the resources mentioned in the `--resources` flag of `terraformer import` command. It did not merge/update the generated `.tfstate` file with the existing `.tfstate` file

Comment: I'm not sure if terraformer is intended for importing part of a collection of resources. Also, if you've told terraformer only to import certain resources, then of course it is only going to import those resources, why would it import everything else?

Comment: I think I was not clear in my explanation. What I meant was that the generated `.tfstate` file for the resources mentioned in `--resources` flag wasn't merged with the existing `.tfstate` file

Comment: Should it have? [Here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67585515/terraformer-merging-multiple-tfstate-files) that might help with merging state files