# Can I update provider-internal state without risking changes to deployed resources?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

After performing a successful `terraform import`, in some cases `terraform plan` will show resources that "will be updated in-place" and indicates only the addition of a few (usually ['Optional'](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/sns_topic_subscription#confirmation_timeout_in_minutes)) arguments.

[image: example plan]

I've not found it documented, but these seem to be attributes used internally by the provider that aren't directly manifest in the deployed resource. The evidence of this is that I am able to run `terraform apply` (and resolve these differences) using a role with read-only access to the AWS account.

I'd like to automate this innocuous `terraform apply` as part of a scripted import process but I also want to ensure that no changes will be made to the deployed resources.

Is there a Terraform command that will set provider-internal state attributes without risk of changing the deployed resources?

Comment: As mentioned, this can be done by careful use of access roles/permissions. I'd like a solution that doesn't depend on such subtleties.

Comment: I do not believe this is possible with the core CLI commands and subcommands.

Comment: I don't know to what extent this is documented, but it may be possible to gain confidence about a plan by reviewing it in JSON form as discussed at [How to show sensitive values](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/how-to-show-sensitive-values/24076/9). The idea is to `terraform show -json plan.out` and review `|jq '.resource_changes[].change.actions'` to understand the plan more precisely.

Comment: [Rover](https://github.com/im2nguyen/rover) or similar may do this already (needs review).

Comment: That fact that this is necessary (especially directly after an import), to me it suggests that the provider is buggy. But I've seen this with multiple providers, so that suggests that Terraform hasn't provided a paved road to help providers implement and test their import handlers.